# SSH connection using putty: using charset "UTF-8" instead of "ANSI_X3.4-1968"?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, charset

When I connect to my Linux server (Ubuntu 14.04) using putty I have some problems because the SSH-connection always uses `ANSI_X3.4-1968` as charset (output of `locale charmap`).

However my system is configured to use `de_DE.UTF-8` which can be seen by `cat /etc/default/locale`:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
```

The used connection profile of putty uses `UTF-8` as *Remote character set* (Window -> Translation). I also tried to use the value `de_DE.UTF-8` here, but there was no change.

The strange thing is that when I log in on the physical console an execute `locale charmap` there I get the correct and expected result: `UTF-8`.

Why do I get different configured charsets using Putty (v0.67) and the physical console? Is this therefore a putty configuration problem, or is the problem on the linux server side?

## Update 1:

I also compared the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` with one from a second similar server that is not affected by this problem and both files were identical. The same is true for the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (both files contain the line `SendEnv LANG LC_*`).

I also executed the following commands to make sure the locales are not defect:

```
sudo locale-gen --purge
sudo update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with PuTTY. What you've configured there is only the *terminal* character set, which tells PuTTY how to *decode* the text it receives – but doesn't pass it to the server in any way.

The locale settings ($LANG &c.) are loaded by the server itself – depending on the distro, either by `source`-ing /etc/default/locale from the shell's startup file (e.g. from /etc/profile), or by loading it via PAM using the pam_env module.

Grep your PAM configurations in `/etc/pam.d` for mentions of `/etc/default/locale`.

- If you find a matching pam_env line directly in an app config such as `/etc/pam.d/login`, copy it to roughly the same place in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. (Pay attention to where in the stack it's located.)
- If you find a matching line in the shared `common-session` config, then make sure the sshd PAM configuration imports it (e.g. via `@include common-session`).
- If you don't find anything in PAM, check the shell's startup files instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I learned a lot, unfortunately it did not solve my problem (see updated question).

Comment: You've compared `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, but have you compared the other files?

Comment: Just made an md5sum of `/etc/pam.d/*` and they are identical on both servers. But I found the important difference. It was `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Looks like someone removed important lines from it.